# Return 2 variables using bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am trying to write a promise function using Bluebird library for nodejs. I want to return 2 variables from my function.
I want the first function to return immediately and the second to complete its own promise chain before returning.

```
function mainfunction() {
    return callHelperfunction()
    .then(function (data) {
        //do something with data
        //send 200 Ok to user
    })
    .then(function (data2) {
        //wait for response from startthisfunction here
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        //handle errors
    });
}

function callHelperfunction() {
    return anotherHelperFunction()
    .then(function (data) {
        return data;
        return startthisfunction(data)
        .then(function () {
            //do something more!
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: what part are you stuck on? your question is more of  a statement. what part isnt working?

Comment: @atmd I am not able to get how to return the value of startthisfunction..I want the value returned by anotherHelperfunction immediately

Comment: Downvoting this, since it's just bad code. Just call the one function then pass the result to the other function as an argument.

Comment: @cleong I don't see why you have to down vote this. It was the approach I followed, I am new to using promises. This may be totally wrong, but atleast I made an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that appears to be wrong is the expectation that `do something with data; send 200 Ok to user;` should be performed in `mainfunction()`, part way through the promise chain in `callHelperfunction()`.

This can be overcome in a number of ways. Here's a couple :

**1. Move `do something with data; send 200 Ok to user;` into `callHelperfunction()`**

```
function mainfunction() {
    return callHelperfunction())
    .catch(function (err) {
        //handle errors
    });
}

function callHelperfunction() {
    return anotherHelperFunction()
    .then(function (data1) {
        //do something with data
        //send 200 Ok to user
        return startthisfunction(data1)
        .then(function (data2) {
            //wait for response from startthisfunction here
            //do something more!
        });
    });
}
```

**2. Dispense with `callHelperfunction()` altogether and do everything in `mainfunction()`**

```
function mainfunction() {
    return anotherHelperFunction()
    .then(function (data1) {
        //do something with data1
        //send 200 Ok to user
        return startthisfunction(data1);
    })
    .then(function (data2) {
        //wait for response from startthisfunction here
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        //handle errors
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just like regular functions only have one return value, similarly promises only resolve with one value since it's the same analogy.

Just like with regular functions, you can return a composite value from a promise, you can also consume it using `.spread` for ease if you return an array:

```
Promise.resolve().then(function(el){
     return [Promise.resolve(1), Promise.delay(1000).return(2));
}).spread(function(val1, val2){
      // two values can be accessed here
      console.log(val1, val2); // 1, 2
});
```

Comment: Promise.resolve(1), will immediately return to the calling function. Is there a reason you put delay? I am sorry I could not follow your answer

Comment: @user1692342 I just put two promises there, the delay was to illustrate that it works with promises that resolve asynchronously too.

Comment: I was reading about spread function. From what I understood, it will wait for both these promises to get over before going to the spread function. What I am trying to do is, return the first value back immediately. the second promise of mine takes 2-3 minutes to complete and once that is over I can return it

Comment: @user1692342 no, promises can't do that, they are singular values. If you want something that is multi-valued you want either an async iterator (pull stream) or an observable (a push stream). Promises represent a singular value you can't "flow" through their chain. I can add an answer using RxJS for observables (which I use) if you'd like. Do you ever need to wait for both to be done? Is there any reason why you can't just `.then` the two promises inside the `then` handler?

Comment: The reason I can't wait for both promises to be done is I want to send a reply to the user immediately once I do basic preprocessing with the request. Once the major time consuming function is done, the user can poll to find if it is completed.

Comment: @user1692342 ok, what about giving that notification in a `.tap` on the "shorter" promise? We also have a guide on "progress/notifcation" in the bluebird github if you'd like.

Comment: If i use .tap will I be able to catch the notification in my calling function? The 2 functions which I have written are in separate files. So i will need my mainfunction to catch the tap! Also I could not find progress/notification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84091/discussion-between-user1692342-and-benjamin-gruenbaum).